# complex equation

Tags: complex-numbers

In Gaussian plane draw solution of equation |z-(1+2i)|=2

My solution:
[image: my sol.]

Wolfram solution:

[image: wolfram sol.]

I don't understand, why my solution is not right. Could anyone help me, please?

Comment: It's supposed to be a circle. Likely your input to Wolfram Alpha was wrong.

Comment: @JM: [You would think so, but you'd be wrong.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=|z-%281%2B2i%29|%3D2)

Comment: Your answer iscorrect. Wolfram|Alpha's is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, W|A seems to be depicting $(1+2i)\pm2$. Now in the *reals* the solutions to the equation $|z-a|=b$ are $z=a\pm b$, but not in $\Bbb C$, so it might have been conflating it with that.

Your depiction of the solution set is perfectly correct.

Comment: Tried it out; apparently Alpha does suck at plotting curves in complex format... oh well.

Answer (score 0):

$|z-(1+2i)|=2 \iff z-(1+2i)=2  e^{i\theta}$ for all $\theta \in\mathbb {R}$

$\iff z=1+2i+2e^{i\theta}$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb{R}$

When we take $\theta = 0, -\pi, -\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$,

we have $z=3+2i$, $-1+2i$, $1$ and $1+4i$.